# nodejs web server and python communication

Tags: python, node.js, web, apache-kafka

I have a simple web which can display stock price streaming of certain stock symbol. The web server is nodejs, the infrastructure for stock processing is kafka, spark with python. The flow is

googlefinnace -> kafka(pythonfile 1) -> spark(pythonfile2) -> nodejs -> web browser

The explanation : kafka and spark process  stock info from google finance, then provide result to nodejs web server. However the stock symbol is hardcode to "FB".
so I wanna user can type desired stock symbol on web, and nodejs can send it back to kafka(pythonfile1). I don't know how to do it between nodejs and kafka . Could anyone weigh in here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are several very good nodejs Kafka clients. I personally use node-rdkafka

https://github.com/Blizzard/node-rdkafka

Using any of these nodejs Kafka clients you can publish or subscribe to any Kafka topic from your nodejs web application.

Comment: Thanks for replying.  My point is how to pass a user-input "stocksymbol" from js  back to kafka server.  Nothing related to kafka broker, topic.

Comment: A Kafka server and a Kafka broker are the same thing so your question is not clear.  If you want to publish from your web app in nodejs to a Kafka application (perhaps written in python) you just publish a Key/Value pair message to a kafka topic that your backend python app is subscribing to. If the symbol is hard coded to 'FB' in your exiting node.js app then just change that part of the code to accept a HTML form from the use and use the provided symbol and either the Key or the Value of your kafka message. Message can be a simple string or JSON.